# Excel 2016 VBA Automatic Time Insertion

Tags: vba, excel, time, excel-2016

I have looked around for an answer on the web but have not found any help regarding what I am attempting to do. I want the time to automatically be entered into the corresponding cell in column B when the column A cell is modified, the same applies for Columns C and D. I do not want the time to update, which is the issue that I am currently encountering. Below is the code I currently have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Target.Offset(, 1) = Time
ElseIf Target.Column = 3 Then
    Target.Offset(, 1) = Time
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This coding works, but it updates the time in columns B and D, which is what I do not want. What could I add to stop the updating of the time?

Thank you <3

Comment: Try `Target.Offset(, 1).value = Now()`

Comment: what do you mean by *I do not want the time to update*? do you mean that only if the B (or D) cell was empty, only then you want to insert the time?

Comment: I wanted it so that the initial time would be inserted and afterwards would not be updated from modifying the cells within the A and C columns. Miqi180's answer fixes what I had and it works the way I want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you only want to update the time if no time is already shown in the adjacent column? In that case this should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 3 Then
        If Target.Offset(, 1) = vbNullString Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Now()
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This is in line with Gary's Student's answer, but adds the conditional and simplifies the code a bit.

Comment: Thank you Miqi180! Your answer is what I was looking for and works great, thanks again! <3